# This server requires an execution environment of JavaSE-1.8, but no valid JRE was found. Caution is advised

Tags: eclipse, server, wildfly, openjdk-11

I use Eclipse 4.9 twice. one with jdk8 and one with openJDK11.
With both I want to integrate Wildfly 14 Runtime via "Window -> Preferences -> Server -> Runtime Environment".
The following error occurs when I select "OpenJDK-11.0.2" under Alternate JRE:

This server requires an execution environment of JavaSE-1.8, but no valid JRE was found. Caution is advised.

Thank you in advance for your views and possibly detailed solutions :)

[image: Eclipse: New Server Runtime Environment]

Comment: It says "enter image description here"; please do it!

Comment: Thanks for the tip.
Do you have any idea how the above problem can be solved?

Comment: @user3804191 did you find workaround?

Answer (score 2):

sorry for my bad English.
To resolve it, go to

> Window -> Preference -> Java -> Compiler

And change the value of `Compiler compliance level` to `1.8`
It work for me.

Comment: It worked as a charm! Thank you Aime.

Answer (score 0):

Install an OpenJdk 11 JRE and rather select that as the execution environment.

That is Window -> Preference -> Java -> Installed JRE's

Although chances are you've already got that one installed so just select it from the execution environment.

Unless there's a good reason why you're wanting to use an alternate JRE.